# bcrypt не сравнивает jwt токены

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, bcrypt

В базе данных находится зашифрованный bcrypt jwt токен и когда я пытаюсь сравнить его с новым созданным токеном он всегда возвращает true, но при этом если я буду сравнивать сгенерированный jwt токен не на моем сайте или если просто что-то другое напишу сравнение отрабатывает правильно.

Как я все это дело проверяю:
Я отправляю post запрос через postman, вот код, который принимает этот запрос:

```
var data = req.body;
    createToken(data.mail);
    async function createToken(login){
        var refreshToken = jwt.sign({login}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '1m'});
        var hashrefreshToken = await bcrypt.hash(refreshToken, 3);
        await usersdb.updateOne({mail: login}, {$set: {verifytoken: hashrefreshToken}});
        res.cookie('id', refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 1000 * 60
        });
        res.send('kyky');
    }
    res.end;
```

Этот код выдает мне токен в cookie, шифрует его и заносит в базу данных, дальше я отправляю запрос по другой ссылке, где я беру cookie из базы данных и сравниваю его с cookie пользователя:

```
var data = req.body;
    var finduser = await usersdb.findOne({mail: data.mail});
    var resultbcrypt = await bcrypt.compare(req.cookies.id, finduser.verifytoken);
    if(resultbcrypt){
        console.log('Сходится');
    }else{
        console.log('Не сходится');
    }

    res.send(req.cookies.id);
    res.end;
```

Comment: Видимо где то в коде есть ошибка...

Comment: Нифига подобного, все перепроверил, без лишнего кода даже

Comment: Верим на слово, ага

Comment: Возможно, если бы вы предоставили больше информации о проблеме, добавили бы код в вопрос с примерами, то и ответ может быть даже нашелся бы... Сейчас, исходя из описания, можно однозначно сказать только одно - что то у вас идет не так и ломается.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос, смотрите

Comment: как я проверяю: сначала я создаю новый токен и заношу зашифрованный в базу данных, а потом снова отправляю пост запрос и снова заношу зашифрованный токен в базу данных, но в cookie пользователю я выдаю старый токен меняя переменную refreshToken в res.cookie на старый токен, соответственно у пользователя он не меняется, а в базе данных он другой уже, и после уже начинаю отправлять пост запрос на источник, который сверяет и он возвращает true, когда в базе данных уже другой токен

Comment: а вот интересно, `{expiresIn: '1m'}` в настройках - это что 1 минута что ли действует токен?  Судя по документации - https://github.com/vercel/ms - именно так. И что это за соль `3` - хотя бы что ли `await bcrypt.hash(refreshToken, bcrypt.genSalt(10) ); ` Ну и можно еще в консоли посмотреть - а что вообще приходит в `req.cookies.id` и `finduser.verifytoken`